# The best methods to report object mesh problems?

Tags: mesh, detection

Hopefully there is an easy way to have Meshlab check and report any and all Mesh problems found in an imported STL mesh file. If there is not a one click method, what is a recommended sequence of steps.

I have an STL object file that requires a repair by the 3D slicer (Cura like) app. I'm trying to figure out what might be wrong with the STL file so that I can fix it.

I searched for solutions on the MeshLab web site. I noticed that previous Meshlab version had selection filters for unmanifold vertex and edges. Now the filters solicit repairs.